# @Autowired annotation in spring-Getting BeanCreationException and java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, autowired

**I have written a small code to check @Autowired annotation in Spring, here is my piece of code.**

```
       package beans;

        //import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutoWired;
        import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
        //import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor;
        import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
        //import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.*;

        public class Car {

            @Autowired
            @Qualifier(value="e1")
            private Engine engine;

            //no need to have setters or constructors here
            public void printData()
            {

                System.out.println("Engine model year: " +engine.getModelyear());

            }

        }



        package beans;

        public class Engine {
            private String modelyear;
            //generate setter and getter

            public void setModelyear(String modelyear) {
                this.modelyear = modelyear;
            }

            public String getModelyear() {
                return modelyear;
            }

        }

    package test;

    import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
    import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
    import beans.Car;
    //import beans.Test;
    public class Client {

        /**
         * @param args
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ap = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("resource/spring.xml");
        Car c=(Car)ap.getBean("c");
        c.printData();

        }

    }

<!--spring.xml-->
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN 2.0//EN"
"http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd">

<beans>
<!-- activate autowire annotation -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>
        <bean id="engine" class="beans.Engine">
            <property name="modelyear" value="2015"/>
        </bean> 
        <bean id="e1" class="beans.Engine">
            <property name="modelyear" value="2016"/>
        </bean>

        <bean id="c" class="beans.Car">
        </bean>
</beans>
```

**When I am trying to run Client.java class ,I am getting following error:
Can someone suggest why I am facing this issue?**

Mar 11, 2017 10:19:24 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@70d18a80: display name [org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@70d18a80]; startup date [Sat Mar 11 10:19:24 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
Mar 11, 2017 10:19:24 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [resource/spring.xml]
Mar 11, 2017 10:19:25 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext obtainFreshBeanFactory
INFO: Bean factory for application context [org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@70d18a80]: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@18d1cf9e
Mar 11, 2017 10:19:25 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext$BeanPostProcessorChecker postProcessAfterInitialization
INFO: Bean 'org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor' is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
Mar 11, 2017 10:19:25 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@18d1cf9e: defining beans [org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor,engine,e1,c]; root of factory hierarchy
Mar 11, 2017 10:19:25 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry destroySingletons
INFO: Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@18d1cf9e: defining beans [org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor,engine,e1,c]; root of factory hierarchy
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'c': Autowiring of fields failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private beans.Engine beans.Car.engine; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/config/DependencyDescriptor;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Set;Lorg/springframework/beans/TypeConverter;)Ljava/lang/Object;
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private beans.Engine beans.Car.engine; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/config/DependencyDescriptor;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Set;Lorg/springframework/beans/TypeConverter;)Ljava/lang/Object;
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/config/DependencyDescriptor;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Set;Lorg/springframework/beans/TypeConverter;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:361)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.injectFields(InjectionMetadata.java:61)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInstantiation(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:414)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:249)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:155)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:246)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:160)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:352)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:66)
    at test.Client.main(Client.java:13)

Set of jars which I am using are:

[List of jars used and reference libraries while creating the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qjj7i.jpg)

Comment: You seem to be using incompatible spring dependencies. Pick a version, and stick to it. Note that all of them are completely obsolete for many years. The current stable version is 4.3.7. Why are you experimenting with 2.5.x?

Comment: Thanks for your input.Can you please tell from where I should get all the relevant jars of spring 4.3.Which jars are needed to run the project?

Comment: http://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/

Comment: Thank you so much JBNizet.I downloaded the latest jars and it worked for me!!!